# The heriditary category $A$-mod

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $K$-algebra ($K$ algebraic closed) and let $A$-mod denote the category of finitely generated modules over $A$.

It seems, (well, I do know) that $A$-mod is a hereditary category. You can read it In Remark 1.2(i) [here](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/ictp2006/lecturenotes/lenzing1.pdf). However, I have not been able to find a standard textbook with a proper proof or at least with an stattement of this fact. Dou you know of any?

I have looked at Atiyah-Donaldson, some papers about quiver representations and the books about categoyr theory I know: MacLane's Category theory, Awodey 2nd edition and Harold Simmons *An Introduction to Category Theory*. And also Cartan-Eilenberg Homological Algebra, but without any succes.

Thank you.

Comment: In the link you provide, the author further assumes that $A$ is hereditary.

Comment: There are some quite natural examples of projective modules over a $K$-algebra admitting non-projective submodules. Try and find some!

Comment: @CaptainLama Oh It is true! I haven't seen during all this time.